# Showing default browser bullet points on a <ul> when using YUI CSS reset

Tags: html, css, xhtml, yui

I'm using YUI 3 CSS Reset on my page, but want to display a specific unordered list using the browsers default list styling.

I've put an example page up on the URL below to explain:
http://www.nsmith.me.uk/list.php

I want to be able to style `<ul>` on the page as if the css reset script wasn't included. For an example, add ?hideReset=1 onto the URL above.

Can anyone let me know what CSS I need to add after the reset to achieve this?

Thanks,
Neil

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need some

```
margin-left: {xyz}px;
padding-left: {xyz}px;
```

(adjust to fit)

and to get the bullets back

```
list-style-type: disc;
```

Comment: I had to put the list-style-type: disc; on the LIs.

Answer (score 1):

You can also load YUI's base.css which will restore most of the settings in a consistent way, once normalized via reset.css.